# Is it possible to open links in an iframe with target="_blank" in the same iframe?

Tags: html, iframe, hyperlink

So is it possible to open links of an external page in an iframe with `target="_blank"` in the same iframe?
Because you can't modify the DOM of the external page?

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery to catch when a link is clicked and then load in the content to the iframe

```
$('iframe a[target="_blank"').live('click',function(e){
e.preventDefault(); //stops it opening in a new window
var url = $(this).attr('href');
$('iframe').load(url);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a target="_parent">click</a>
```